# Is there a free voip api for android

Tags: java, android, voip

I am developing an application where I need to implement **VOIP**.
It is about connecting 2 devices using WIFI to transmit conversation (voice).

**My question is:** Is there a free API or SDK that I can use in my application?

Comment: checkout https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/

Comment: thanks for the reply but i would like with apache or psd licence

Answer (score 5):

See here :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html

Here is a demo app:http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html

you can also use third party api ([here](http://www.twilio.com/client/mobile))

Comment: :( thank you for reply but Twilio is not free i must payed 1/4C every minute